# Node js Joi validation conditional disallow keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, joi

I am new to nodeJS, so forgive me if my question sounds stupid, 
I want to support conditional payload based on another key,

```
price: Joi.when('pricing', {
    is: 'VARIABLE',
    then: Joi.number()
        .min(1)
        .max(1000)
        .required(),
    otherwise: // prevent adding price in the payload
})
```

I want the user to provide price value if pricing is equal to '**VARIABLE**' otherwhise to prevent user providing price in the payload.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Joi Documentation](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0#anyforbidden), we can use the `Joi.forbidden()` or `Joi.any().forbidden()` to disallow any keys in your schema. In your case, your final schema will be:

```
price: Joi.when('pricing', {
  is: 'VARIABLE',
  then: Joi.number().min(1).max(1000).required(),
  otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
})
```